# How does Guice inject classes without an @Inject-annotated constructor?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, guice

I'm trying to understand how DI is used in our codebase (Kotlin). We are using google guice for dependency injection.

Here is a sample class:

```kotlin
class ServiceClass @Inject construct(
     private val depA: DepA,
     private val depB: DepB
) { ........ }
```

In Module class:

```kotlin
@Provides
fun provideDepA(): DepA {
 //constructs DepA object and returns it
}
```

DepB class:

```kotlin
class DepB { .... }
```

As far as I know for the variables annotated with `@Inject`, Google Guice will look to resolve those dependencies using module class. So it makes sense how `DepA` object is injected.

But what about `DepB`? How are we able to inject DepB without specifying it anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guice bindings that are not declared in modules are known as [Just-in-time Bindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings), and by default Guice is willing to call constructors that take zero arguments:

> #### Guice Wiki: JustInTimeBindings
>
> Guice can create bindings for concrete types by using the type's injectable constructor. Guice considers a constructor injectable if:
>
> - **(recommended)** The constructor is explicitly annotated with @Inject (both `com.google.inject.Inject` and `javax.inject.Inject` are supported).
> - or, the constructor takes zero arguments, **and**
>
>   - the constructor is non-private and defined in a non-private class (Guice supports private constructor only when it is defined in a private class, however, private constructors are not recommended because they can be slow in Guice due to the cost of reflection).
>   - the injector has not opted in to require explicit @Inject constructor, see explicit @Inject constructors section below.

If you haven't [required explicit bindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings#enforce-explicit-bindings) and you have a public no-arg constructor, Guice will call it as if you had marked it with `@Inject`. This is in contrast to Dagger, which will *only* call [`@Inject`-annotated constructors](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/#declaring-dependencies):

> #### Dagger Dev Guide
>
> If your class has `@Inject`-annotated fields but no `@Inject`-annotated constructor, Dagger will inject those fields if requested, but will not create new instances. Add a no-argument constructor with the `@Inject` annotation to indicate that Dagger may create instances as well.
>
> ...
>
> Classes that lack `@Inject` annotations cannot be constructed by Dagger.

In both Guice and Dagger you can construct the objects yourself in `@Provides` methods, and in Guice you can also use a Module to [explicitly bind to a constructor](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ToConstructorBindings#constructor-bindings) with arguments and without an `@Inject` constructor.